# Multiple references to database sequence [hibernate_sequence] were encountered

Tags: spring, hibernate, jpa, spring-boot

I'm getting this error when building my JHipster application:

> org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'entityManagerFactory' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/orm/jpa/HibernateJpaAutoConfiguration.class]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is org.hibernate.HibernateException: Multiple references to database sequence [hibernate_sequence] were encountered attempting toset conflicting values for 'increment size'.  Found [1] and [50]

I see the 50 [here](https://github.com/dancancro/great-big-example-application/blob/blogwithkotlin/src/main/resources/config/liquibase/changelog/00000000000000_initial_schema.xml#L13), but I don't know where the 1 is coming from.

Since the last time it worked, I have added a few new entities defined in [these](https://github.com/dancancro/great-big-example-application/tree/blogwithkotlin/src/main/kotlin/org/exampleapps/greatbig/domain) Kotlin files.

I'm working on adding the [Thinkster conduit demo](https://github.com/gothinkster/realworld) as one feature into my application. On its own the demo builds and runs without any problems. To get where I am now, I copied the code from the demo into my app and adjusted a few things, mostly related to the User entity. Since JHipster doesn't let you add fields to User, I created an Author entity with a 1:1 relationship to it. That in itself probably doesn't have anything to do with this error. I figure that something in this new code must be trying to create a sequence and the default increment size is one.

Answer (score 4):

You're probably missing a few tags that are required since JHipster makes a lot of assumptions about project setup.  This is what was necessary to get my project working:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "tags")
public class Tag {
  @Id
  @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.SEQUENCE, generator = "sequenceGenerator")
  @SequenceGenerator(name = "sequenceGenerator")
  private int id;
}
```

Standard hibernate would let you get away without specifying the strategy or generator, but since it was configured already you need to match.

Answer (score 2):

The problem is your sequence generator annotation does not have **sequenceName** specified so it uses common **hibernate_sequence** sequence in database. The sequence has its increment and you apparently try to specify a different.

So even if you specified the sequence generator for your table, it is actually shared with your other generators and "1" is from this hibernate_sequence.

Just try to name your sequence so it has its own entity in the database and you should be OK with any increment size.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem, some entities had :

```
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private Long id;
```

while some other entities had :

```
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.SEQUENCE, generator = "sequenceGenerator")
    @SequenceGenerator(name = "sequenceGenerator")
    private Long id;
```

I changed all the entities in the project to the first type i.e. AUTO and got rid of my abstract class DomainEntityBase which had the @Id and this solved the issue.
P.S. I'm using jhipster.

Answer (score 0):

Create a new sequence in your DB using a name different from "hibernate_sequence", then use that sequence in your @SequenceGenerator and also specify the name of the schema the sequence was created under. Example, if you have defined your schema this way:

```
CREATE SEQUENCE wallet.wallet_sequence
  INCREMENT 1
  MINVALUE 1
  MAXVALUE 9223372036854775807
  START 1
  CACHE 1;
```

Then your entity annotation should be as follows:

@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.SEQUENCE, generator = "hibernate_seq")
@SequenceGenerator(name = "hibernate_seq", sequenceName = "wallet_sequence", schema = "wallet")